how to accept cookies from a site with selenium
I create this code with selenium to click the cookie button, because I have to accept cookies to access web site data
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
wbe = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
wbe.get('https://www.asianbetsoccer.com/it/nextgame.html')
wbe.implicitly_wait(10)

wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/button").click()

but it gives me an error because it doesn't find the button:
wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/button")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_resp
onse
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/button"}
  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=124.0.6367.91); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troub
leshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF754EB1502+60802]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754E2AC02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754CE7CE4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D36D4D]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D36E1C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D7CE37]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D5ABBF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D7A224]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D5A923]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D28FEC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754D29C21]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7551B411D+3217821]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7551F60B7+3488055]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7551EF03F+3459263]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF754F6B846+823494]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754E35F9F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754E30EC4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754E31052]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF754E218A4]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFCEC3E7AC4+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFCEDC2A4E1+33]

can I use selenium or do I have to use another method?
I have to click to this button that, so it isn't a pop up
and then this window appears in which I have to click "Accetta tutto" and "Salva e continua"

You have to check if the "Accept cookies" thing is an alert or popup or what ever. According to that you can use different approaches.

You might want to complete your XPath. Like this it won't match.

That is the full path

maybe first run without --headless to see web browser and to see if you really get this button. Maybe sometimes you doesn't get it. OR maybe it needs more time to display it and you have to use time.sleep(...) or you need bigger value in implicitly_wait(10). OR maybe you have to run it in try/except to catch error when button doesn't show up.

are you sure it is correct xpath? usually xpath start with  // - and if button is not directly in body (but nested in other element) then it needs also  //  - like //html/body//button

and another idea - if button is in <iframe> then first you have to find this iframe and use driver.switch_to.frame() because Selenium treats frame as seperate page and it needs to switch to frame to search inside this frame

BTW: it seems there are many buttons on page - you may need to use better xpath to get correct button. Maybe it has some ID to get it - button[@id=...]. Or you may try to search by text button[text="Accetta tutto"]

You have wrong xpath.
Path /html/body/button searchs button directly in body but button is in some div which is another div, etc. And this needs to use // to get nested element without using full path:
/html/body//button or shorter //button
But there are many buttons on page and using only //button will find first button on page - which is not button with Accetta tutto - so you have to use id or text() to find correct button.
This works for me
wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accetta tutto']").click()

or using contains() if you want to search only part of text
wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Accetta tutto')]").click()


Full code which I used for tests:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
#chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless=chrome')

wbe = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
wbe.get('https://www.asianbetsoccer.com/it/nextgame.html')
wbe.implicitly_wait(10)

#wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/button").click()   # it can't find butotn
#wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body//button").click()  # it finds wrong button 
wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accetta tutto']").click()  # this works for me
#wbe.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Accetta tutto')]").click()  # this works for me


input('Press ENTER to close')

